# Cannot access fetched files in python API

Tags: python, dart, http, post

I have created a web API without any frameworks in python. I want to send a image to the API using POST request (no problem if you have solution using GET request) and I will store the image in my local storage. I can able to save the image and the size of the stored image is same as the size of the sent image but the stored image is not opening and it says some error which I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

And this is my code:

```
import os
import shutil
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_cors_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self._set_cors_headers()
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/predict':
            content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
            file_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            filename = self.headers.get('filename', 'image.jpg')
            save_path = f'./yolov5/data/images/{filename}'

            with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(file_data)

            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()

        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()

            response_data = {
                'Hello': 'World'
            }
            response_json = json.dumps(response_data)

            self.wfile.write(response_json.encode())

        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()


def run_server():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8000
    server_address = (host, port)

    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
    print(f'Starting server on {host}:{port}...')
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server()
```

And these are the codes that I used to send POST request.

Python code:

```
import requests
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict'
files = {'image': open('D:/image.jpg', 'rb')}
res = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(res)
```

Dart code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

void some() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict');
  final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
  request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('image', "D:/img.jpg"));
  final response = await request.send();
  print(response);
}

void main() {
  some();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in the way you are receiving the file data in your POST request handler, because you're directly writing the raw POST request content to the file. Lets try to parse the received data as a multipart/form-data request.

You gonna need to  install `python-multipart`

edit: the content_type variable isn't being parsed correctly to extract the boundary, lets try to do that correctly.

```
import os
import shutil
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json
from io import BytesIO
from multipart import MultipartParser

def extract_boundary(content_type):
    if 'boundary=' not in content_type:
        return None
    return content_type.split('boundary=')[-1]

class RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_cors_headers(self):
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS")
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")

    def do_OPTIONS(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self._set_cors_headers()
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        if self.path == '/predict':
            content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
            content_type = self.headers['Content-Type']
            boundary = extract_boundary(content_type)

            file_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
            parser = MultipartParser(BytesIO(file_data), boundary)
            for part in parser:
                if part.filename:
                    filename = part.filename
                    save_path = f'./yolov5/data/images/{filename}'
                    with open(save_path, 'wb') as f:
                        shutil.copyfileobj(part.file, f)

            self.send_response(200)
            self._set_cors_headers()
            self.end_headers()

        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()

            response_data = {
                'Hello': 'World'
            }
            response_json = json.dumps(response_data)

            self.wfile.write(response_json.encode())

        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.end_headers()


def run_server():
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 8000
    server_address = (host, port)

    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, RequestHandler)
    print(f'Starting server on {host}:{port}...')
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server()
```

Comment: @Saxtheown I tried your code but I am getting the following error:
File "main.py", line 37, in do_POST
    parser = MultipartParser(BytesIO(file_data), content_type)
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\multipart\multipart.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self.boundary = b'\r\n--' + boundary
TypeError: can't concat _io.BytesIO to bytes